# Set maximum size of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm starting my journey with Java and I'm playing with swing. I made some simple *JFrame* with *JScrollPane* inside and I'm looking for a way to restrict my frame to preset minimum and maximum size. I've searched the net about *setMaximum* and *setMinimum* and how wrong they are, but I haven found nothing(Except some weird *ComponentListener*). However *setMinimum* is working fine(at least for now) but i can't get *setMaximum* to work. How can I set such constraints?

**EDIT:**
What I mean by "Except some weird *ComponentListener*" is that it lets me resize frame, then just resize it back. What I want to achive is invisible bound, that prevents frame from going more.

**EDIT2:**
It seems that this problem concerns my OS(which is OSX), *ComponentListener* works fine on Windows. But on Mac, when I start dragging the window out, *ComponentMoved* is called and only when I release mouse button *ComponentResized* is called. When I copy code from *Resized* to *Moved*, first, window resize itself over *MaximumSize* for fraction of second, then apropiet code is called and everything is fine, but this flicker is far from acceptable. I've even overloaded *paint(Graphics g)* to first reset size and then call *super.paint* but with same result.

Comment: `Except some weird ComponentListner` - then you have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) to your frame and check into `componentResized(ComponentEvent e)` if the new values for width&height are allowed and, in case they are, you resize the frame through `setSize`.

Comment: But it lets me resize it, then just resize it back. What I want to achive is invisible bound, that prevents frame from going more.